# What is wrong with my world?

Tags: terraria-console

So in Terraria, I was in my friend's world helping him get rid of the crimson biome on Xbox One. Then, I went back onto my world to do something, but then it was the same world as my friend's. You couldn't open the chests and there was nothing in them because I could break them. Does anyone know what is happening? Can anyone tell me how to fix it? I've restarted my Xbox One as well as Terraria.